# RDP Shortcuts with changing passwords

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

I am looking to create a script that opens multiple RDP shortcuts.
These are mostly to the same server, using different users with the same password.
This password rotates regularly and I do not want to save the credentials.
I have found numerous variations of the same script, however I cannot get them to work for me at all.

Current script:

```
cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like "*target=TERMSRV/*"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace " ","" -replace "Target:","")}}
$Server="<hostname>"
$User="<username>"
$Password = Read-Host "Please enter Windows Password" -AsSecureString
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server
cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like "*target=TERMSRV/*"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace " ","" -replace "Target:","")}}
```

The problem I have with the above, is that even though I have specified a username, it still brings up the login prompt for the last user that has logged in, instead of logging in using those credentials above.

I have tried without the last and first line (deleting the credentials after and before using it)
I have tried with an actual password saved for testing, but that didn't work either.

I have tried other variations of the same script to no avail.

Commands I have tried instead:

```
cmdkey /generic:$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
```

```
cmdkey /add:$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
```

```
cmdkey /add:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
```

None of the above has worked.

Another thing I was hoping for, is to use the RDP shortcut files, however I have had no luck with that either.